# How to display the first two authors in a citation call-out?

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I am trying to find a way to cite and display in the text both the first and the second co-author of a publication.

Example:

```
@article{Leech_2011,
    doi = {10.1523/jneurosci.5626-10.2011},
    url = {https://doi.org/10.1523%2Fjneurosci.5626-10.2011},
    year = 2011,
    month = {mar},
    publisher = {Society for Neuroscience},
    volume = {31},
    number = {9},
    pages = {3217--3224},
    author = {R. Leech and S. Kamourieh and C. F. Beckmann and D. J. Sharp},
    title = {Fractionating the Default Mode Network: Distinct Contributions of the Ventral and Dorsal Posterior Cingulate Cortex to Cognitive Control},
    journal = {Journal of Neuroscience}
}
```

If both R. Leech and S. Kamourieh were first joint authors, `\citep{Leech_2011}` would only display Leech.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Most bibliography styles at least give the option of listing all authors if not just two but this depends entirely on the bibliography style you use and you have given no information about that or even whether you are using bibtex or biber. (texstudio is just the file editor so not involved, I deleted that tag)

Comment: I want to display the first co-authors in the text but not necessarily in the references section. In the references section, I do not care if all names appear, I only care to make visible in the main text the joint first co-authors....

Comment: as I said this depends on the style you are using but you have provided no example for anyone to suggest changes or test answers you can always just use `R. Leech and S. Kamourieh, \cite{...}` you know who the authors are it's not essential that the citation system knows to distinguish those two from the other two.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I take it that you employ the `natbib` citation management package. If that's the case, you could use the package's citation aliasing capabilities -- specifically, the `\defcitealias` and `\citepalias` commands -- to create the required form of the citation call-out.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@article{Leech_2011,
    doi = {10.1523/jneurosci.5626-10.2011},
    url = {https://doi.org/10.1523%2Fjneurosci.5626-10.2011},
    year = 2011,
    month = mar,
    publisher = {Society for Neuroscience},
    volume = {31},
    number = {9},
    pages = {3217--3224},
    author = {R. Leech and S. Kamourieh and C. F. Beckmann and D. J. Sharp},
    title = {Fractionating the Default Mode Network: Distinct Contributions of the Ventral and Dorsal Posterior Cingulate Cortex to Cognitive Control},
    journal = {Journal of Neuroscience}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
\setlength\bibhang{0pt} % optional
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat} % or some other suitable bib style
\defcitealias{Leech_2011}{Leech, Kamourieh, et al., 2011} % <-- new

\usepackage{xurl} % for easy line breaks in long URL strings
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} % optonal

\begin{document}

\citep{Leech_2011}

\citepalias{Leech_2011} % <-- new

\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 Wow, I have read the `natbib` documentation many times during the years but `\defcitealias` apparently always eluded me. Man lernt nie aus...